# docx with track change producing incorrect output in Apache Tika

Tags: ms-word, apache-tika

I am parsing docx files using apache tika.

```
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ContentHandler contentHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFileName));
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();

OfficeParserConfig officeParserConfig = new OfficeParserConfig();
officeParserConfig.setIncludeDeletedContent(false);
parseContext.set(OfficeParserConfig.class, officeParserConfig);

parser.parse(inputStream, contentHandler, metadata, parseContext);
System.out.println(contentHandler.toString());
```

When I am sending track_revised docx file it's adding all the text deleted with the actual text and inserted text. Is there a way to tell parser to exclude the deleted text?

Answer (score 1):

I did figure it out

```html
AutoDetectParser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
ContentHandler contentHandler = new BodyContentHandler();
inputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(inputFileName));
Metadata metadata = new Metadata();
ParseContext parseContext = new ParseContext();
OfficeParserConfig officeParserConfig = new OfficeParserConfig();
officeParserConfig.setUseSAXDocxExtractor(true);
officeParserConfig.setIncludeDeletedContent(false);
parseContext.set(OfficeParserConfig.class, officeParserConfig);

parser.parse(inputStream, contentHandler, metadata, parseContext);
System.out.println(contentHandler.toString());
```

Comment: This works. Do you have any more information about the SAX Docx extractor? The documentation mentions that it's "experimental". Do you know why? Are there any use-cases I should look out for if I set `setUseSAXDocxExtractor(true)`?

Comment: There is a PR in the repo that need to be merged. other than that I am not sure